# How to restore the deleted database from sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server-2008

I deleted a database from SQL Server 2008 R2 by mistake and I need that database to be restored again? I do have backups of 10 days old. But I need that database so that those 10 days of work can be saved and it will affect my carrier as well.

Any ideas or suggestions or 3rd party tool?

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: If you deleted all the database files and haven't backed them up anywhere the only (possibly forlorn) hope would be to stop using the server immediately and try some file system recovery software that can recover deleted files.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for your reply. I just deleted one database, did some changes to the other databases and realised my mistake. I tried to open transactional logs but that option was disabled.

Answer (score 4):

See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/159870/how-to-recover-the-database-which-is-accidently-deleted-using-sql-server-2008).

Short version: you *might* be able to recover the deleted `.mdf` and `.ldf` files if you **stop using the server right now** and use some sort of undelete utility to recover the physical files. If you able to recover them, then simply re-attach the `.mdf` file.

If you aren't able to recover the physical files, the best you can do is restore as recent as your most recent backup, in this case, 10 days...

Comment: I new to the database concepts, what you mean by "some sort of undelete utility to recover the physical files" ?

Comment: It's not a database concept, rather an operating system one. Your goal is to recover the physical files used by SQL Server. Google "undelete untility" to find third-party programs capable of this.